# How to create a dashing like widget object in javascript

Tags: javascript, gridster, dashing

I am trying to create a widget/tile object to display on my page. Basically its a rectangular box with a background color which I would like to display some text in.

To be specific I want to create widgets like the ones in dashing (dashing.io).

I am kinda  new to JS/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class=widget>
<h2>Some text</h2>
</div>
```

CSS: You can change the values

```
.widget {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
h2 {
 margin: auto;
}
```